# Black and white areas on GameObject after generating lightmap in Unity 2020.3

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I want to use baked lighting in my Unity scene. After baking the lightmaps, I am left with black and white artifacts on the baked GameObjects (see [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bd3G.jpg) for an example).

Unity states, that UV maps of the objects are overlapping but doesn't show any overlaps in the UV Overlap Scene view ([Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6njR.png)).
Any try to either fix the UV overlap or to change the lightmap settings have not shown any effect.

As suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466166/unity-probuilder-black-white-lines-when-baking-lightmaps), I tried the following to fix the issue:

- Ran "Generate Lightmap UV's" on the GameObject on import
- Made sure "Auto Lightmap UVs" is enabled
- Ensured the objects are Static
- Ensured the light is Static, and set to Baked (or Mixed)
- Opened the lighting settings, and reset to default
- Increased Padding and Max Spacing to full
- Unchecked 'Stich Seams' on the GameObject.
- Set the Directional Light's Normal Bias to 0.
- Tried different Lightmapper Methods
- Tried different Lighting Modes

Only increasing the size of the objects by an enormous amount seems to partially resolve the problem, but still results in some artifacts and is unfortunately not really feasible (see [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaXSQ.png)).

Are there any other possible reasons for this to happen or solutions you could suggest?

Comment: This question is going to get shot down here. I don't have an answer for your specific problem, but you'll have better luck finding someone who does on the Unity forums